# Why do the non-elected mods pro temp still have diamonds?

Tags: support, election, moderators

The election ended several days ago, and the newly elected moderators  were given their powers immediately after. Yet the two mods pro tempore—[Mark Rogers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/35/mark-rogers) and [DampeS8N](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51/dampes8n)—who did not run (and thus, did not win) have [maintained their diamonds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about):

[image: Mod list]

This is, as far as I'm aware, contrary to every other election thus far on Stack Exchange. Why have they kept their powers?

Comment: Same reason Facebook kept "deleted 3 years ago" photos? :)

Comment: *"Diamonds are forever."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, my bad.

>_<

Comment: No biggie :) I thought maybe you guys were testing out some new transition workflow for mods with SciFi.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me I don't know, it may have something to do with losing trained and trusted moderators.

But I won't really mind if it gets stripped, I was planning on a more passive role anyway.

Comment: I've wondered this all myself.